# Split an array into mutiple arrays based on a value - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What I've tried so far : I have an array as shown below, what i wanted to do is, create multiple arrays based on the value `BEGIN_DAY`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_DAY
            [1] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130701
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 3060
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130702
            [1] => 270
            [2] => 757
            [3] => 13812810
            [4] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130703
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 3894971
            [4] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130704
            [1] => 290
            [2] => 478
            [3] => 5119617
            [4] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => END_DAY
            [1] => 15
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_DAY
            [1] => 16
        )
     [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130704
            [1] => 290
            [2] => 478
            [3] => 5119617
            [4] => 1
        )
```

and so on ...
I want to split this array into multiple different arrays when ever it begin with `BEGIN_DAY` so it should look like this:
The first :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_DAY
            [1] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130701
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 3060
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130702
            [1] => 270
            [2] => 757
            [3] => 13812810
            [4] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130703
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 3894971
            [4] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130704
            [1] => 290
            [2] => 478
            [3] => 5119617
            [4] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => END_DAY
            [1] => 15
        )
```

The second :

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_DAY
            [1] => 16
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130704
            [1] => 290
            [2] => 478
            [3] => 5119617
            [4] => 1
        )
```

What I've tried so far :

```
$days=array();
$split_by='BEGIN_DAY';
foreach ($day_all as $key => $value) {
    if($day_all[$key][0]==$split_by){
         $days=array_slice($day_all, 0,$split_by);
  }
}
 var_dump($days);
```

Much Appreciated!

Comment: A LOOP. Every time you want to reformat an array, a loop is your choice. Not some random calls to syntax sugar functions, but a loop with straight and clear logic inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sk = "first";
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if(in_array(BEGIN_DAY, $value)&&$key!=0)
    {
        $sk = "second";
    }
    $result[$sk][] = $value;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
$first = $result['first'];
$second = $result['second'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
$yourArray = ...; //is your array as described above
$finalArray = [];
$tempArray = [];
for($idx = 0; idx<$yourArray .length; idx++){
  $tempArray = $yourArray[$idx]

  if($yourArray[$idx][0] == 'BEGIN_DAY'){
    $finalArray[] = $tempArray;
    $tempArray = [];
  }
}
```

The final array will contain the arrays. Each time the `BEGIN_DAY` is found, the array will be inserted into the finalArray and a new one is created.
To improve the code, check the existence of the cell too, to avoid index exception.